# creating invoice is not working through Paypal REST API

Tags: php, paypal

I am facing the problem to create the PayPal invoice through the REST API. I got the access token by using auth API of https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token. I am passing the token in the HEADER to create an invoice in the create invoice API of https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/.

**Header**:
[image: Paypal Header]

Below is my JSON body.

```
{
  "merchant_info": {
    "email": "krpdas-facilitator@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "prabhu",
    "last_name": "kr",
    "business_name": "prabhu kr",
    "phone": {
      "country_code": "91",
      "national_number": "2222233333"
    },
    "address": {
        "line1": "xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxx",
        "city": "xxxxxxx",
        "state": "xxxxxx",
        "postal_code": "888888",
        "country_code": "IN"
    }
  },
  "billing_info": [
    {
      "email": "lalith-facilitator@abacies.com",
        "business_name": "test facilitator",
        "additional_info": "test facilitator's Test Store",
        "address": {
            "line1": "1 Main St",
            "city": "San Jose",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": "95131",
            "country_code": "US"
        }
    }
  ],
  "shipping_info": {
    "first_name": "Lalith",
    "last_name": "Kumar",
    "address": {
      "line1": "1234 Main Street",
      "city": "Anytown",
      "state": "CA",
      "postal_code": "98765",
      "country_code": "US"
    }
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Zoom System wireless headphones",
      "quantity": 2,
      "unit_price": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "120"
      },
      "tax": {
        "name": "Tax",
        "percent": 8
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Bluetooth speaker",
      "quantity": 1,
      "unit_price": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "145"
      },
      "tax": {
        "name": "Tax",
        "percent": 8
      }
    }
  ],
  "discount": {
    "percent": 1
  },
  "shipping_cost": {
    "amount": {
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": "10"
    }
  },
  "note": "Thank you for your business.",
  "terms": "No refunds after 30 days."
}
```

I tried with changing the access token and merchant email ids. But always I am getting the same error as 401 unauthorized. I am following the documentation of https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/.

**ERROR:**

```
{
    "name": "AUTHORIZATION_ERROR",
    "message": "Authorization error occurred.",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors",
    "debug_id": "f89a30f937ced"
}
```

**Scope:**

```
"scope": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture 
https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer 
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card openid 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment",
```

Comment: What does your header look like?

Comment: i have authorization and content-type in header

Comment: That should be alright. How do you pass your token? Like this: `Authorization: Bearer $token`?

Comment: yes i have attached the screen shot in the question now

Comment: Take a look at the response you get when requesting your token. What does it say for `scope`?

Comment: i could n't add in the comment ..so i added in the question itself. Please see that

Comment: The URL you're requesting is not in your scope. That could be the problem.

Comment: Ok..can you please suggest me how to add?

Comment: In your Paypal developer account, under My Apps > [Your App], make sure that the invoicing feature is enabled in the APP SETTINGS section.

Comment: Ok thanks..let me check

Comment: My invoicing feature is enabled already in my app setting..see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWsRM.jpg) @Tobias Geiselmann

Comment: @lalithkumar Can you recheck the token generation? Also its worth to check what's the test account under that.

Comment: i created the two app and generated the token..but same error i am getting..what did you mean the test account? @Sripaul